# Limit time range selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

On my site, the user has the opportunity to select the date-time range. I implement this using the DatePicker from the react-datepicker library.

I set up the date range in such a way that the end date could not be less than the start date (which is quite logical). That is, for the end date, the user can select dates only after the start date (or itself). It works.

But I have problems to set up exactly the same functionality over time. This is complicated by the fact that I need to set the time range up to seconds.

So I will explain with an example what I need:
If the user has selected a start date and time of 11/06/2022 12:20:20, then the time in the end date must start from 12:20:20.

```
    () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
  <>
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm:ss"
      timeIntervals={1}
      isClearable
      timeCaption="Time"
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy    HH:mm:ss"
      
      selectsStart
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
    />
    
    <DatePicker
      selected={endDate}
      onChange={(date) => setEndDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      isClearable
      timeFormat="HH:mm:ss"
      timeIntervals={1}
      timeCaption="time"
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy    HH:mm:ss"
      
      selectsEnd
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      minDate={startDate}
    />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

The issue is `minDate` is only applicable for selecting the date

#### Solution

1. Define a function to filter the time you want to allow like below. `time` input is what the user going to select.

```
const filterPassedTime = (time) => {
  const selectedDate = new Date(time);
  return selectedDate.getTime() > startDate.getTime();
};
```

2. Set the above time filter function to the second input using `filterTime` prop like below.

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  ...
  filterTime={filterPassedTime}
/>
```

Working Example

[image: Edit ecstatic-jang-hbymj0]

Comment: @Павел, Check this out !!

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much. I will answer your answer as correct.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell me how to solve a small problem here: how can I make timeIntervals be determined by seconds, not minutes.

Comment: This might be helpful for that => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226519/react-datepicker-time-selection-with-seconds